# Where did the lower two equations come from?

Tags: coordinate-systems, vectors

[image]

From this graph I want to know how do the vectors $i$ & $j$ relate to the vectors theta & r as the lower two equations here show

Comment: Please write out your question in full, including the necessary equations. Screenshots/photos should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

> Where did the lower two equations come from

Multiply both sides of equation (3.2.6) by $\sin(\theta)$.

Multiply both sides of equation (3.2.7) by $\cos(\theta)$.

Add those two equations together. You will see that the $\hat i$ term on the RHS drops out. The $\hat j$ term can be greatly simplified using an identity from trigonometry, which will give you equation (3.2.9) for $\hat j$ in terms of $\hat r$ and $\hat \theta$.

The equation (3.2.8) for $\hat i$ is obtained similarly.

Answer (score 1):

$\hat r$ and $\hat \theta$ are unit vectors parallel and perpendicular to the position vector of point $P$.

$\hat i$ and $\hat j$ are unit vectors parallel to the $x$ and $y$ axes respectively.

The relationships between these two pairs of vectors are given by the two pairs of equations. In each pair of equations $\theta$ is the angle between the position vector of $P$ and the $x$ axis.

To derive 3.2.8 you multiply 3.2.6 by $\cos \theta$; multiply 3.2.7 by $\sin \theta$; and subtract one from the other. 3.2.9 is derived in a similar way.   If you know some linear algebra you can think of the coefficients in each pair of equations as a 2x2 matrix, and the two matrices are inverses of one another.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways of showing this.

Easiest is to realize that all you're doing is applying a linear transformation to the $\hat x$ and $\hat y$ basis; i.e.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
r \\\theta
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta && \sin\theta  \\ -\sin\theta && \cos\theta\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 x \\  y
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and if you calculate the inverse matrix (it is invertible since its determinant is 1 and not zero), you get

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta && -\sin\theta  \\ \sin\theta && \cos\theta\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
r \\  \theta
\end{bmatrix}.
$$